# html content changes when using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to extract the attribute value of src from a block of html, the html block is :

```
<img class="product-image first-image" src="https://cache.net-a-porter.com/images/products/1083507/1083507_in_pp.jpg">
```

my code is :

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.net-a-porter.com/us/en/product/1083507/maje/layered-plaid-twill-and-stretch-cotton-jersey-top'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
if url.find('net-a-porter')!=-1 :
  i = soup.find_all('img', class_="product-image first-image")[0]["src"]
  print i
```

the result i get:

```
//cache.net-a-porter.com/images/products/1083507/1083507_in_xs.jpg
```

but i want to get what is exactly in original html, which should be:

```
https://cache.net-aporter.com/images/products/1083507/1083507_in_pp.jpg
```

my result is different from the original `src` value, the `http:`is gone, and `1083507_in_pp` changes to `1083507_in_xs`. I don't know why it happens, does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: solve what? What is the desired result? :)

Comment: want to get the jpg url in src

Comment: try attaching the src value to the url value, with a string concatenation

Comment: but they are not the same.

Comment: ? of course they're not the same, why would you attach them if they were the same

Comment: https://www.net-a-porter.com/us/en/product/1083507/maje/layered-plaid-twill-and-stretch-cotton-jersey-top/cache.net-a-porter.com/images/products/1083507/1083507_in_xs.jpg

Comment: Or you're gonna have to be more descriptive of what you want to accomplish. Not sure I can understand what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: sorry i think i haven't make my question clear, already edited

Answer (score 0):

You are close, however, you need to access the `"src"` key from the builtin `attrs` key:

```
if url.find('net-a-porter')!=-1 :
  i = soup.find_all('img', class_="product-image first-image")[0]
  print i['src']
```

Comment: sorry but it is not what i want to ask, already edited my question, thanks.